# Routing is not working in MVC Web API and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, rest, model-view-controller, angularjs-routing

I am using MVC Web API and Angular JS

When i am giving single routeProvider, then its working after adding one more routeProvider its not working....

My Code Is:

```
   var phoneModelsApp = angular.module('phoneModelsApp', ['ngRoute']);

   phoneModelsApp.config(['$routeProvider', 
   function ($routeProvider) {    


  $routeProvider.when('/phonelist', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/Test1.html',
      controller: 'phoneListCtrl'
  }).
 $routeProvider.when('/phonelist1', {
     templateUrl: 'partials/Test2.html',
     controller: 'phoneListCtrl'
 }).       
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/phonelist'
    });
  }]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add to in your urls "#" or adding in your configuration:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

In order to remove the # in Angular you need to make an small change in your configuration:

You need to add:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

This is the whole version:

```
myApp.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  $routeProvider
    .when('/page1', { template: 'page1.html', controller: 'Page1Ctrl' })
    .when('/page2', { template: 'page2.html', controller: 'Page2Ctrl' })
});
```